# WKWebView is not displaying video controllers on ipad ios 12

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, vimeo

[image]I have a video that is hosted on a webpage, the problem the video is not playable from ipad having a ios version 12, it just shows an image placeholder and no play button

I am trying to have the video play controllers shown

Answer (score 0):

Everyone is having this problem. It's a bug at Vimeo's end. They changed something on their server that broke your app. The fix has to come from Vimeo.

Either that, or drop support for iOS 12. In iOS 13, WKWebView handles the Vimeo change just fine.